# Why does find comand return "Permission denied" when it is command substituted and stored to a variable within a bash script

Tags: bash

So I am trying to find empty files that may exist in my project, as well as prevent their existence in future. I am doing this in a bash script like so.

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

if [[ "$(find . -type f -empty -not -path "./node_modules/*" | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]]; then
  echo "[check-for-empty-files] Empty files found. $(find . -type f -empty -not -path "./node_modules/*" -ls)"
  exit 1
else
  echo "[check-for-empty-files] No empties."
fi
```

... and it works as expected.
However, the issue here is I'd like to store the find cmd in a variable like so:

```
empty_file_cmd=$(find . -type f -empty -not -path "./node_modules/*")
```

... so that I could use it in other places in the script.
However this returns "Permission denied" and I cannot seem to figure out why that happens, given that the prior implementation does not return the "Permission denied" error.

Comment: Do you want to store the command string in a variable? Or the results of the command execution (because that's what you're currently doing)?

Comment: @majusebetter I want to store the command string in a variable so that I could reuse it in other areas too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store command lines in variables. For one thing, you'll screw up field separation and substitution. Instead use a function:

```
myFindCmd() {
  find . -type f -empty -not -path "./node_modules/*"
}

myFindCmd  # execute it whereever you like
```